Splines smoothing. Unity spline package
So I'm creating a script that generates splines for car trajectories by using points I placed on prefabs and Unity built-in splines package.
I ran into a problem that using AutoSmooth function makes trajectory deviate from its original linear path.
I understand that problem is connected with how bezier curves and tangents In/Out work, but what logic do I need to implement in order to fix it?
I'm looking forward for any ideas!



You might want to rephrase your question a little. At least I do not completely understand the problem, as smoothing could impossibly result in the identical trajectory as then... there would be no smoothing.

@BitTickler I need to smooth only the the "turn parts" I guess. Currently smoothing affects straight parts before and after the turn aswell

I recently had a similar problem. While it might not be an option for you (because unity) - but I did not use splines for that, but my own fitting to a polynomial, because those extra arguments you need for splines are kind of counter-intuitive, depending on what you try to do. But either way - you best only interpolate the curves and leaves the straights as they are.
